# Bouncing ball in Android skips velocity

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, draw

I have a ball that only moves in a straight line and it bounces from the top and bottom of the screen. Every time it does that the velocity is reduced by 2. The ball has a radius of 50.

It works fine but when the velocity reaches 4 and hits the next wall, it goes to 0 instead of 2 and then the next time it hits a wall to 0.

Why is that?

```
private fun update() {
    if (ball.posy > 0) {
        if (ball.direction == "+") {
            ball.posy += ball.velocity
        } else {
            ball.posy -= ball.velocity
        }
    }
    if (ball.posy >= height - 50) {
        ball.direction = "-"
        ball.velocity -= 2
    } else if (ball.posy <= 50) {
        ball.direction = "+"
        ball.velocity -= 2
    }
    invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
private fun update() {
    if (ball.posy > 0) {
        if (ball.direction == "+") {
            ball.posy = min(ball.posy + ball.velocity, height - 50)
        } else {
            ball.posy = max(ball.posy - ball.velocity, 50)
        }
    }
    if (ball.posy >= height - 50) {
        ball.direction = "-"
        ball.velocity -= 2
    } else if (ball.posy <= 50) {
        ball.direction = "+"
        ball.velocity -= 2
    }
    invalidate()
}
```